# Which is right: “on Manhattan” or “in Manhattan”?

Tags: prepositions

I want to meet some persons in Manhattan but I'm not sure how to message them about it.

> I'll meet you **on** Manhattan.
>   (OR)
>   I'll meet you **in** Manhattan.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Manhattan%2Con+Manhattan&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Manhattan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20Manhattan%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It depends.  Are you *on* the island or *in* the borough?

Comment: Presumably the fact that it is an island was more important and relevant to the choice of preposition back in the day when there were few bridges, and as yet no tunnels, and ferry crossing was common.  We still say "on Nantucket" and "on Assateague" but "on Manhattan" is rare compared to "in Manhattan".  Nowadays we can say "downtown Manhattan" because it's perceived mainly as an urban area not as an island.